# Multidict in python not working ?? How to create it?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to create an python multi dimensional dictionary :-
Currently i am doing like this
multidict = {}

IN LOOP

```
   mulitdict[i] = data
```

if loop runs ten times I am getting same value in all index..
Eg:
I want to have like this

```
multidict {0 : {'name':name1, 'age' : age1}, 1: {'name':name2, 'age' : age2}
```

but i am getting as shown below

```
multidict {0 : {'name':name1, 'age' : age1}, 1: {'name':name1, 'age' : age1}
```

I also tried the  default dict also....but every time i  get same value in all index. What is the problem?

Tried code :

> ```
> csv_parsed_data2 = {}
> with open('1112.txt') as infile:
>   i =0
>   for lineraw in infile:
>       line = lineraw.strip()
>       if 'sample1 ' in line:
>           ### TO GET SOURCE ROUTER NAME  ###
>           data['sample1'] = line[8:]                 
>       elif 'sample2- ' in line:
>           ### TO GET DESTINATION ROUTER NAME  ###
>           data['sample2'] = line[13:]
>       elif 'sample3' in line:
>               ### TO GET MIN,MAX,MEAN AND STD VALUES  ###
>               min_value = line.replace("ms"," ")
>               min_data = min_value.split(" ")
>               data['sample3'] = min_data[1]
>               csv_parsed_data2[i] = data
>               i = i + 1
>               print i,'::',csv_parsed_data2,'--------------'
> print csv_parsed_data2,' all index has same value'
> ```

any efficient way to do this??

Comment: Where is the code that you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds you are assigning the same `data` dict to each of the values of your outer `multidict`, and just modifying the values it holds on each pass through the loop. This will result in all the values appearing the same, with the values from the last pass through the loop.

You probably need to make sure that you create a separate dictionary object to hold the data from each value. A crude fix might be to replace `multidict[i] = data` with `multidict[i] = dict(data)`, but if you know how `data` is created, you can probably do something more elegant.

Edit: Seeing your code, here's a way to fix the issue:

```
csv_parsed_data2 = {}
with open('1112.txt') as infile:
  i =0
  data = {}                             # start with empty data dict
  for lineraw in infile:
      line = lineraw.strip()
      if 'sample1 ' in line:
          ### TO GET SOURCE ROUTER NAME  ###
          data['sample1'] = line[8:]                 
      elif 'sample2- ' in line:
          ### TO GET DESTINATION ROUTER NAME  ###
          data['sample2'] = line[13:]
      elif 'sample3' in line:
              ### TO GET MIN,MAX,MEAN AND STD VALUES  ###
              min_value = line.replace("ms"," ")
              min_data = min_value.split(" ")
              data['sample3'] = min_data[1]
              csv_parsed_data2[i] = data
              data = {}          # after saving a reference to the dict, reinitialize it
              i = i + 1
              print i,'::',csv_parsed_data2,'--------------'
print csv_parsed_data2,' all index has same value'
```

To understand what was going on, consider this simpler situation, where I a values in a dictionary after saving a reference to it when it had some older values:

```
my_dict = { "foo": "bar" }
some_ref = my_dict

print some_ref["foo"] # prints "bar"    

my_dict["foo"] = "baz"

print some_ref["foo"] # prints "baz", since my_dict and some_ref refer to the same object
print some_ref is d   # prints "True", confirming that fact
```

In your code, `my_dict` was `data` and `some_ref` were all the values of `csv_parsed_data2`. They would all end up being references to the same object, which would hold whatever the last values assigned to `data` were.

Comment: thanks a lot blcknght...can you explain again to me I am not getting , and also good way to do it

Comment: @Python_Dude: Updated with a fix to your code and more explanation.

Comment: Understood ..but i cant reinitialize  the data... it has some value so i used multidict[i] =dict(data)....its ok right... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
multidict = {}
for j in range(10):
    s = {}
    s['name'] = raw_input()
    s['age'] = input()
    multidict[j] = s
```

This will have the desired result